# Mysql AFTER UPDATE trigger with IF-THEN condition, but no data insertion

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, insert

I created the following AFTER UPDATE trigger on the table ***manage_transaction*** using IF-THEN condition in order to insert the specific data into the table  ***manage_site_income_details***   BUT, neither a single row is inserted into ***manage_site_income_details*** nor any error encounters. However, I modified my IF-THEN condition many times, but no success.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS
        `upon_subscription_payment`;
CREATE DEFINER = `test-db-ru-admin`@`%` TRIGGER `upon_subscription_payment` 
AFTER UPDATE
    ON
        `manage_transaction` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF 
       OLD.about LIKE 'SUB' AND NEW.status = 'Completed' 
    THEN
    INSERT INTO 
                manage_site_income_details
    VALUES(
        NULL,
        OLD.t_id,
        OLD.txn_id,
        'SUB_Fee',
        OLD.fee,
        NOW());
    END IF
```

Comment: Good news - your code works fine..

Comment: But, as I mentioned no row is inserted into manage_site_income_details

Comment: It does when I test it - you can improve your question..(well you know the rest)..

Comment: How is this issue different from your previous two questions?

Answer (score 0):

No problem here or https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8UYVnC2xQsWuSC9VBZz6BN/0

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS T;
drop table if exists `manage_transaction`,manage_site_income_details;
create table manage_transaction(t_id int,txn_id int,fee int,about varchar(3),status varchar(15));
create table manage_site_income_details(id int,t_id int,txn_id int,txt varchar(20),fee int,dt datetime);
insert into manage_transaction values (1,1,10,'sub',null);

CREATE  TRIGGER T 
AFTER UPDATE ON `manage_transaction` 
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF OLD.about LIKE 'SUB' AND NEW.status = 'Completed' THEN
       INSERT INTO manage_site_income_details
       VALUES(
        NULL,
        OLD.t_id,
        OLD.txn_id,
        'SUB_Fee',
        OLD.fee,
        NOW());
    END IF;

update manage_transaction
    set status = 'completed';

select * from manage_site_income_details;

+------+------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+
| id   | t_id | txn_id | txt     | fee  | dt                  |
+------+------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+
| NULL |    1 |      1 | SUB_Fee |   10 | 2020-05-29 09:58:04 |
+------+------+--------+---------+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: You've set your about field to sub, but as he's using like, I assume it's not just sub, it's sub-mike or something like that.  If you set the about to something other than sub, it won't insert.

Comment: @Mike would someone with the OPs profile make such a mistake?

Comment: I encounter two issues:   1) Mysql shows error on the line where NOW() is used. 2) the my trigger T should be triggered  when the 'status'  field in manage_transaction has already been 'Completed'.

Comment: I already realized that @Mike could not understand my problem. But, still Thank You.

Comment: @P.Salmon has proved there is nothing wrong with the trigger and I also ran his script myself and all was fine on that, it doesn't error and it does insert.  Can you show some of the manage_transaction data that you would expect to fire the insert?  And to answer the question "would someone with the OPs profile make such a mistake?"  They put like instead of =, so it is possible

Comment: @AmirAfzaal  I had one thought on issue one.  If you're running this on the command line, you need to set the delimiter  "delimiter //" as the default is semicolon, so it will error on the semi colon on the now() line.

Comment: You should be able to copy my code, paste into your environment and run it. - Any problems?

Comment: @P.Salmon  Your code in db fiddle has the delimiter line but the one you pasted here doesn't.

Comment: @mike very true but that's a quirk of db-fiddle..Take it out (and the begin..end) in the trigger and it fails to syntax (failure to syntax is not the op's problem)

Comment: But he did say it errored on the line with now(), which is the one with the semicolon.  Anyway, lets see what @AmirAfzaal has to say.

Comment: @mike possibly because published code is missing a terminator after end if (but that may be a transcription error)

Comment: @P.Salmon I used your code as it was and created trigger, but still no entry goes to the table manage_site_income_details  I am still unable to understand WHY doesn't it work although IF condition fulfilled AFTER UPDATE event of manage_transaction.